# Output XML elements inside element with foreach with XSLT

Tags: html, xml, xslt, foreach, model

I have a small issue with outputting elements inside an element in a for-each.

Basically, I want to output a selectbox with languages and for that selectbox I want to output 3 input fields, based on elements in a model.

The model look like this:

```
<Languages>
  <Language name="ar" selected="false">Arabic
    <Skills>
      <Skill id="1" selected="false">Speak</Skill>
      <Skill id="2" selected="false">Read</Skill>
      <Skill id="4" selected="false">Write</Skill>
    </Skills> 
  </Language>
 <Language name="bg" selected="false">Bulgarian 
    <Skills>
      <Skill id="1" selected="false">Speak</Skill>
      <Skill id="2" selected="false">Read</Skill>
      <Skill id="4" selected="false">Write</Skill>
    </Skills> 
 </Language>
 <Language name="ca" selected="false">Catalan 
   <Skills>
      <Skill id="1" selected="false">Speak</Skill>
      <Skill id="2" selected="false">Read</Skill>
      <Skill id="4" selected="false">Write</Skill>
  </Skills>
 </Language>
</Languages>
```

What I want is to output the some HTML to like like this

```
<ul>
 <li class="language">
    <select>
     <option value="ar">Arabic</option>
     <option value="bg">Bulgarian</option>
     <option value="ca">Bulgarian</option>
    </select>

    <input type="checkbox" value="speak" />
    <input type="checkbox" value="read" />
    <input type="checkbox" value="write" />
 </li>
</ul>
```

My current XSLT is this:

```
<xsl:variable name="languages" select="$model/descendant::Languages" />

<select name="lang[]">
   <xsl:for-each select="$languages/Language">
      <option><xsl:value-of select="text()" /></option>                                                                                                         
    </xsl:for-each>
 </select>
```

I somehow have to get into each language and do a foreach on Skills

```
<xsl:for-each select="./Skills/Skill"></xsl:for-each>
```

I just can't quite figure out how.

The idea is that the user can dynamically add new languages, the user speaks, reads or writes, and upon reentering the form, the selected inputs and selections will be marked and filled out.

Comment: Will each language have the same three skills? (i.e Could you just look at the first language to get the skills for the check boxes?)

Comment: Each language will have the same three skills... The attribute "selected" will be set to true for the specific language the user have selected that he/she speaks, reads or writes, f.x. Bulgarian, and the user have selected speaks, reads for that. So I don't think I can look at the first language, when the model will be returned with changed attributes when the user posts the selections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this `xsl:for-each` after your current `select` for the languages

```
     <xsl:for-each select="$languages/Language[@selected='true']/Skills/Skill">
         <input type="checkbox" value="{.}">
             <xsl:if test="@selected='true'">
                 <xsl:attribute name="checked">checked</xsl:attribute>
             </xsl:if>
         </input>
     </xsl:for-each>
```

This selects the skills for the currently selected language, and renders a check box for each one, checking the one that is marked as selected.

Note the use of Attribute Value Templates here, to output the value attribute.

EDIT: In response to your comments, to further this approach, consider having a template matching `Language` where you would output the `Select` and the following check boxes.

You could initially call this template using only selected languages, like so:

```
<xsl:variable name="selectedLanguages" select="$languages/Language[@selected='true']"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="$selectedLanguages"/>
```

You could then check if there were any selected languages, and if not, call the template with the first language instead

```
 <xsl:if test="count($selectedLanguages) = 0">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="$languages/Language[1]">
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:variable name="languages" select="/Languages"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:variable name="selectedLanguages" select="$languages/Language[@selected='true']"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$selectedLanguages"/>
      <xsl:if test="count($selectedLanguages) = 0">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="$languages/Language[1]">
            <xsl:with-param name="selectedName" select="''"/>
         </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:if>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Language">
      <xsl:param name="selectedName" select="@name"/>
      <select name="lang[]">
         <xsl:for-each select="../Language">
            <option>
               <xsl:if test="@name=$selectedName">
                  <xsl:attribute name="checked">checked</xsl:attribute>
               </xsl:if>
               <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
            </option>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </select>
      <xsl:for-each select="Skills/Skill">
         <input type="checkbox" value="{.}">
            <xsl:if test="$selectedName != '' and @selected='true'">
               <xsl:attribute name="checked">checked</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
         </input>
      </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note the use of the parameter `selectedName` to differentiate between the cases where you want to select the language, or whether this is the initial display.

Comment: That will output a checkbox valued "Speak" for each language.., so I get a bunch of checkboxes outputted...

Comment: My apologies! I've corrected this so that it now outputs the relevant value for each skill.

Comment: Hmm... I will still get the three checkboxes outputted for each language... So I have one selectbox, but 3 checkboxes x every language = 432 checkboxes 

But I might thinking about this the wrong way ...

Comment: The code should only output skills for the currently selected language. If you see, I do `Language[@selected='true']` in the `xsl:for-each` (So for the XML in your question, you should have no checkboxes displayed, because no languages are selected!)

Comment: Ahhh... I might have explained it very badly! My apologies.
When no selection have been made, it will only display one selectbox and 3 checkboxes, with no marked boxes (selected = false). The user selects reads, writes, speaks for one language, add a second language, select reads, writes for that language. When the user sees the form again, there will be two li's, each with a selectbox and three checkboxes, with the users selections (selected = true).